# Does Mathematica assume real variables in this case?

Tags: functions, series-expansion

When we have a function like $f(x) = x^2-1$ and we expand it in a power series about some $x = x_0$, does Mathematica automatically assume that $x$ is real valued?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I do not believe so.  However, if `f[x]` is not analytical `x0`, the result depends on the direction in the complex plain at which `x0` is approached.  See the documentation.

Comment: If you have a function like your example $f$, the power series will be the same polynomial whether we assume $x$ is real or complex.  You might want to give an example in which it matters in the same way it matters in your actual problem.  For instance, `Abs[x]`; try `Series` on it with and without the assumption that $x$ is real.

Comment: Thanks to both for your contribution. @Michael E2, I have tried with your example and indeed it has a difference in that case. My specific example turns out to be the one in my OP. I guessed that by expanding about x = 1, I'm implying to Mathematica that x is real. What do you think?

Comment: I don't think it implies `x` is real for Mathematica.  What does it matter, though?  The answer for `x` is real is the same as the answer for `x` is complex. You could add `Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]`, if you want to indicate that `x` may be assumed to be real.